# How to do complex port forwarding (sort of)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a very different situation. My laptop named A, another machine B(ip-172.16.28.3) with ssh server installed and i have an account on that machine, the third machine C(ip-172.16.24.3) is a proxy server.
All the machines are within a LAN, but

1- Machine B can connect to A as well as C

2- Machine A i.e.my pc, it can only connect to B and not C

Now to use internet, i do the following:

ssh -X user@172.16.28.3

Then i type firefox and i use the firefox of machine B with proxy setings as 172.16.24.3:3128

Instead of using firefox of B, i want to use my local firefox.
Is there a way through which i can connect to C via B and use my local firefox for browsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since laptop A has ssh access to B, and B has access to port 3128 on machine C, you can set up port forwarding to bind port 3128 on machine C to port 3128 on your local computer (A). Then you can set up firefox proxy settings on your laptop to localhost:3128 and it will be using port 3128 on machine C for proxy services.

```
ssh -L 3128:172.16.24.3:3128 user@172.16.28.3
```

Explanation:

```
-L = Take a remote port and bind it to some local port
3128 = The local port to bind to
172.16.24.3 = The remote host (proxy server) who's port you want access to.
3128 = The port on the remote host (proxy server) that you want access to.
user@172.16.28.3 = the ssh server
```

This method can be used to gain access to any port on any machine that the ssh server can see on the network (one port at a time).

Once a connection is established, you can set up firefox on your laptop just as it is on machine B except use localhost:3128 instead of 172.16.24.3:3128 in the proxy settings.

("localhost" should be the same thing as 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, but it is not working because i don't have an ssh account on 172.16.24.3. I can't even connect to 172.16.24.3 directly. You have used user@172.16.24.3 instead of user@172.16.28.3, as a result the above request simply times out!

Comment: @adnan kamili Sorry I mixed up the addresses. I think I fixed it.

Comment: 172.16.28.3 is the ssh server and 172.16..24.3 is the proxy server, you made a mistake! but ssh -L 3128:172.16.24.3:3128 user@172.16.28.3 also does not work.

Comment: @adnan kamili At what point does it fail to work? Are you able to connect to the ssh server? Does it fail when you try to use firefox? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes it connects to ssh server. When i put proxy 127.0.0.1:3128 in firefox the request simply times out.

Comment: @adnan kamili What do the proxy settings on machine B look like (screen shot)?

Comment: I traced the error using proxychains for one proxy:                    |DNS-request| google.com 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:3128-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-|DNS-request| scl2-sync1317.services.mozilla.com 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:3128-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--timeout
      Everytime it shows that 4.2.2.2:53

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar with proxychains. I would try to do nmap localhost to make sure that port 3128 shows up. If it does not, maybe you don't have privileges on your computer to bind to local ports... maybe try a different port or use sudo. You could try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 in the firefox settings. Make sure that all the proxy settings are exactly the same as the proxy settings on machine B (except replacing localhost for 172.16.24.3).

Comment: I use tor sometimes, so obviously i have privileges to bind to local ports on my laptop. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort. I will try look for some workaround.

Comment: @adnan kamili It might be that its just not able to resolve names since socks uses the local DNS server by default. You can change it in firefox's about:config if your using socks5 (network.proxy.socks_remote_dns = true). http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2006/12/07/paranoid-browsing-with-squid/  Good luck.

Comment: It still times out. I tried using ip address of google instead of url again a time out!

Comment: It is working in my friend's laptop but not mine, I have lamp server installed in my system, can that be the reason

Comment: my nmap 127.0.0.1 output: PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
2002/tcp open  globe
3128/tcp open  squid-http
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
9050/tcp open  tor-socks

Comment: It worked atlast, i was using 127.0.0.1:3128 as socks proxy in firefox, i should have used it as http proxy, since there is a http-squid proxy installed on 172.16.24.3. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `-D` argument allows `ssh` to create a SOCKS proxy which you can then connect to with Firefox.

Example:

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:9051 user@172.16.28.3
```

Then you open Firefox and set `127.0.0.1` with port `9051` as a SOCKS5 proxy.

For more information, see [`man ssh`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh).

Comment: It doesn't work, if i use ssh -D 9999 user@172.16.28.3 and use 127.0.0.1:9999 as proxy in local firefox, nothing happens because 172.16.28.3 is not a proxy server

Comment: I also tried proxychains, to chain the local proxy server created using ssh -D  with 172.16.24.3 and results are somewhat weird.         |DNS-request| www.google.com 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9999-<>-172.16.24.3:3128-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--denied

Comment: ssh -D 127.0.0.1:9051 user@172.16.28.3 , still the same